# Mat-autocomplete either doesn't bind or validate

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, material-design

I'm working on an Angular6 application with Material Design and ReactiveForms and I'm having some trouble getting validation/binding to work on a Material auto-complete control.

As far as i know, i need the `[formControl]` to bind my values and the `formControlName='countryid'` in combination with `required` attribute for reactiveforms validation.

The problem is, I can either get the lookup to work OR the validation but not both for some reason. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the mentioned attributes and the underlying binding, but I just don't see the problem. I tried different combinations and workarounds but to no avail.

Does anyone see where I messed up? Thanks in advance.

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhekyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several imports missing from your `app.module.ts` in the stackblitz that had to be resolved before I could review.

I also am not sure what was in `app.component.html` so I commented it out and just called the `<m-add-place></m-add-place>` selector there as I believe that is what you wanted someone to look into.

---

Your first issue is `[formControl]="countryAutoCompleteControl" formControlName="countryid"`...

**those both are `FormControls` and you are essentially assigning two `FormControls` to the same input.**

> - `countryAutoCompleteControl` is a standalone `FormControl` created as    a class variable.
> - `countryid` is a `FormControl` within the    `addPlaceForm`

---

I started by removing `[formControl]="countryAutoCompleteControl"` as you don't need it. I also removed `required` from your input as it is also not needed... you already have required here `countryid: ['', Validators.required]`

```
<input matInput formControlName="countryid" type="text" placeholder="Pick one"
       aria-label="Number" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

In your `ngOnInit` change it to this to do the same thing.. only using `countryid` from your `addPlaceForm`

```
 // this.countryAutoComplete = this.countryAutoCompleteControl.valueChanges.pipe(
     this.countryAutoComplete = this.addPlaceForm.get('countryid').valueChanges.pipe(
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qy4nrm?embed=1&file=src/app/addplace/addplace.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, Im not at home right now but I’ll check it out asap. I take it the attribute isnt needed because thats standard Angular Forms while the Validators syntax is rxjs?

Comment: Correct, the attribute is 'template driven forms' and the validators syntax is 'reactive forms'